# Web Scraping in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape review of the Air Canada airline in the trip advisor web page using python BeautifulSoup with 100 entries. Here is the link I would like to scrape

https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Airline_Review-d8728998-Reviews-Air-Canada.html#REVIEWS

which includes the column Username, Title, Rating, Review Summary, Date posted

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: inspect the page with your browser, find some table identifiers and start coding